# Socket X Android

Tags: android, socket, websocket

Estou fazendo estudo de *socket* no Android (Um *app* de *chat* com mais algumas funções em outras telas) mas devido ao pouco conhecimento no momento fiquei 'travado' em um ponto. Como eu posso criar uma única conexão com o *socket* no *app* em que eu possa usar essa mesma conexão em todo o *app*?

Pensei em cria-la na classe `BaseApplication` mas ainda não obtive sucesso.
Caso alguém possa me sugerir algo agradeço.